# Weird behavior for iab mapping in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to use `iab` mapping for inserting time-tag to my `Tex` document. (So that I could know where to look for the notes when converting notes to tex files.)

I tried to define the following in `c:\vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\tex.vim`:

```
" iab mapping for inserting time stamps.
iab <buffer> sj % <c-r>=strftime("20%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")<cr><ESC>o
```

However, pressing `sj<space>` in insert mode will given me the following:

```
% 2015-04-06 09:23:48

i  sj            2015-04-06 09:23:48
```

Only through pressing `sj<CR>` will the desired output be inserted:

```
% 2015-04-06 09:27:57
<blank line>
<cursor here, in insert mode>
```

Does anyone have a clue of why suth `i  sj            2015-04-06 09:23:48` should have been inserted? How may I stop it?

All the best,

-Linfeng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you defined the abbreviation in `c:\vim\vimfiles\ftplugin\tex.vim`, which seems to be inside the installation path of Vim. You probably should define it inside your user directory, in order to avoid losing those changes when you update it; this is explained at [Vim FAQ 26.1](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.1).

Your abbreviation works fine here. It is possible that your abbreviation is triggering another abbreviation that you have set; you could avoid it by replacing `iab` with `inorea`. You could also list all existing abbreviations with `:iab` and insert mode mappings with `:imap` in order to check which one could be interfering.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is the recursive `iab` mappings defined in two places (`_vimrc` and `~\ftplugin\tex.vim`) that are causing the problem. [I have used the same mapping `sj` to trigger the action of tagging the time in different settings. This is the origin of such recursive structure.]

Comment: it turns out that changing all `iab` to be `inorea` does not help solve my problem. Pressing `<space>` will emit the same set of junk output, while pressing `<enter>` does the job. I think this question is yet partially solved.